# Creating class instances at run-time and initializing simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I am attempting following code to create multiple instances of a class at run-time and want to initialize also, but it is giving error:

> A local variable named 'inum' cannot be declared in this scope because
>   it would give a different meaning to 'inum', which is already used in
>   a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static int i=0;

    class A
    {
        public A()
        { 

        }
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        string inum = "i";
        for (int j=1;j<=5;j++)
        {
            inum = inum + j.ToString();
            //Initialize Instance
            A inum = new A();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context of what you are actually trying do instead of this made up example!

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong: you have a string named `inum` and an inner loop with second variable `A inum`. Rename the second one so it doesn't conflict with the outer.

Comment: The second variable name is changing. You can see the concatenation.

Comment: @RPK the name of a variable is a compile time constant. In your case it's inum. what you are changing is the runtime value of that variable.
The problem is that you have to variables named inum. If you explain what you want to achieve some one might be able to help you. It looks like you simply need an array

Comment: I want to count number of instances and want to determine performance impact on each instance. I will be adding few methods later in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use variable names "dynamically". That doesn't work in C#, and you should change how you think about variables. If you want to create several instances, declare an array:

```
public class MyClass
{
    static A[] instances;

    class A
    {
        public A()
        { 

        }
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        instances = new A[5];
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            instances[j] = new A();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving error: "The name 'instances' does not exist in the current context" at lines where instances is written in the Run() method.

Comment: @RPK: Then you haven't got the same code as I've got. The code I've given compiles. I can't tell what's wrong with what you've got now...

Comment: Ya it worked. I may have missed something, later I copied the whole and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have dynamic variable in c#. The append you are trying is appending the value not the variable pointer.

rather use this way

```
   Dictionary<int, A> inum = new        Dictionary<int, A>();
    for (int j=1;j<=5;j++)
    {

        //Initialize Instance and add to dictionary
        inum.Add(j, new A());
    }
```

You can get them by key name. There are several other way to store instances as collection

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C# programmer by any stretch of the imagination, but by the rules of Java and any other similarly syntaxed language I know anything about, what you are doing is attempting to redeclare 'inum' with a new type, after it has been declared as a string in the same scope.

The other point is that even if this were not the case, you are not creating multiple instances but filling the same variable with a new instance 5 times, which would only result in one instance (the last one).

From quickly reading a C# tutorial I think this is something like what you want. I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the 'inum' variable so it is gone, as is static variable 'i':

```
public class MyClass 
{

    class A
    {         
        public A()
        {

        }
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        // Declare array to hold instances
        A[] instances;
        // instances is now five elements long
        instances = new A[5];
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            //Initialize Instance
            instances[j] = new A();
        }
    }
}
```

That should result in an array of 5 objects called 'instances' in the scope of the Run method - you may want this in the scope of the class itself, possibly as a static property.

As a side note, it's good practice to start at 0, not 1, for operations like this (with the var 'j') and the above code reflects this.

Comment: It is not displaying any result. Probably instance is not initializing and not reaching constructor of class A. I added: Console.WriteLine(...), but the pointer is not reaching there.

Comment: What result do you want to display and where (in the code) do you want to display it?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call the variable of type A "inum" (there exists already one called like that)

you have to give it another name like:

```
A anyOtherName = new A();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to name the variable `A` with different name

```
A objA = new A();
```